# Save form and show when re-opening

Tags: c#, save

I have made a program were I open a file, then, the program takes the first row of the file and place it to the **first** column of a DataGridView. For each row of the **second** column, the user has 3 values of a combobox to select from.

After publishing and opening the executable program I have to open a file from a openFileDialog and choose the comboboxes. **BUT, when I close and reopen neither the file is opened or the comboboxes selected. I need them to be.**

I need the actions made to be saved so the next time I open the program, the values of the comboboxes to be selected.

What do you suggest?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //  opens **BROWSE**

            openFileDialog1.Title = "select CSV for check ";

            string filename = "";
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                textBox1.Text = filename;






                string line;
                // Read the file and display it line by line.

                //read the path from textbox
                System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(textBox1.Text);

                stringforData = file.ReadLine();      
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    // puts values in array 
                    fileList.Add(line.Split(';'));
                }

                file.Close();



                this.ToDataGrid();
            }


     }



private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox2.Clear();
    //*************  PUTS COLUMN 2 TO A STRING[]  ************************
            string[] colB = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                colB[i] = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
          }
 //*************************************************************************



 public void ToDataGrid()
        {
            string[] split = stringforData.Split(';');


            foreach (string item in split)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: save the values to user settings, read and restore on reopen...

Comment: @Mitch How do I save the values to user settings ?

Comment: So you want persistence of data, for a published app that would typically be an SQL server, for something smaller and more local, XML serialization is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply not close the program, and disable it instead. This way you don't need to save anything, it's all still there, just not shown.

To do this, set `YourForm.Enabled = false;` to hide it, and `true` to show it.

Comment: How would the user reactivate the application?

Comment: What if the user restarts the computer ?

Comment: I guess i understood it wrong the first time, his need is clearer now that he provided us with code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to save your settings somewhere where they won't be lost when the program is closed.  A simple way to do this is to write them to a file.  For a *very* simple example, you could use this code to save variables:

```
        List<string> variables = new List<string>();
        variables.Add(variable1);
        variables.Add(variable2);
        File.WriteAllLines("settings.txt", variables);
```

And this code to load them again when the program starts.  Be sure to check if the file is there before trying to read it, since it won't be there on the first run.

```
        List<string> variables = File.ReadAllLines("settings.txt");
        string variable1 = variables[0];
        string variable2 = variables[1];
```

**I wouldn't use this code by itself in a published app**, it is just an example of the basics.  There are lots of potential issues.  If the user doesn't have admin rights, you'll get exceptions if the app is running in certain folders like Program Files.  If somehow the current directory changed during the program's running, saving to a relative path like above might not save in the same place each time, and you'll need to determine the absolute path you want to save to.  IO operations like this need to be surrounded with good error checking and handling.

There are also ways to save variables to the registry, though I don't like doing that.  Saving settings is something that almost every desktop app needs to do.  I believe .NET doesn't include standard functions for reading/writing ini files.  You can use the Win32 functions with DLLImport but that's ugly.  I wrote my own which I use in all of my apps.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I successfully managed to save the info that is important in two files with the WriteAllLines method. It is important now, when I open the program again the two files are loaded in the DataGridView again. Can you help me with this ?